# Getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, looked, cannot find an example thats the same

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing a "tweet checker" code for my AP Computer Science Class. The code is supposed to check that the length of the tweet is within the 140 character limit and, if so, prints the amount of hashtags, @, and links used. I am using the .split method to put all the characters into an array, and then I am accessing the array with for loops to find the specific characters.

I keep encountering a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, which I know means that I am trying to access a nonexistent element in my string, such as element 46 for an array of 46 characters, but I do not know what the exact problem is here. I got harped on last time for not "looking hard enough" but I have searched for over 2 hours on only this subject, and I am simply a high school student.

I appreciate all the help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math; 

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter a tweet:");
      String tweet = scan.nextLine();
      int length = tweet.length ();
      String[] tweetArray = tweet.split ("");
      int c = 0;
      int d = 0;
      int e = 0;
      int i = 0;
      if (length > 140)
        System.out.println("Excess Characters: " + (length - 140));
      else
      {
        System.out.println("Length Correct");
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
          if (tweetArray[i].equals("#"))
          {
            if(!tweetArray[i+1].equals(" "))
            {
              c++;
            }
          }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Hastags: " + c);
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
          if (tweetArray[i].equals("@"))
          {
            if(!tweetArray[i+1].equals(" "))
            {
              d++;
            }
          }
        }
          System.out.println("Number of Attributions: " + d);
          for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
          {
            if((tweetArray[i].equals("h")) || (tweetArray[i].equals("H")))
            {
              if(tweetArray[i+1].equals("t") || tweetArray[i+1].equals("T"))
              {
                if(tweetArray[i+2].equals("t") || tweetArray[i+2].equals("T"))
                {
                  if(tweetArray[i+3].equals("p") || tweetArray[i+3].equals("P"))
                  {
                    if(tweetArray[i+4].equals(":"))
                    {
                      if(tweetArray[i+5].equals("/"))
                      {
                        if(tweetArray[i+6].equals("/"))
                        {
                          if(!tweetArray[i+7].equals(" "))
                          {
                            e++;
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        System.out.println("Number of Links: " + e);
      }




}
}
```

Comment: The best way to debug this sort of thing is to use a *debugger*. If you aren't using one, stop what you're doing right now and install one so you *can* use it. It will dramatically increase your understanding of the code you write, dramatically increasing how fast you learn. There are multiple reasonable-quality free Java IDEs out there (Netbeans, IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, Eclipse), all with built-in debuggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop, `i` correctly iterates from `0` to the maximum length. However you have code such as:

```
 tweetArray[i+1]
 ...
 tweetArray[i+7]
```

that will fail once `i` reaches (or gets close to) its maximum. That is, you are referencing past the end of the array.

In general, if you need to check something about the *next* character, you need to check that it exists first (as you only know that the current character exists).

You may wish to review your whole approach though. There does not appear to be any need to split your string into characters. You could instead use string based functions to count the number of `@` characters or check for the presence of a string (eg. `http://`). Check out [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: Ok, how might I fix that?

Comment: @SeanTheSaxMan One would think that not giving the array an index out of bounds will solve it.

Comment: Ok, I understand why my code will fail, now my question is, how can i check that the next character is not a space, without giving the code a way to fail?